# premake5 How can I generate the projects relative to where the user call premake, and not relative to the premake5.lua file?

Tags: lua, premake

I want the workspace and project files generated relative to where the user call premake5, as right now, everything is relative to the premake5.lua location.

I tried to use the location command in my workspace, but I'm unable to find a function that return the folder where the executable is call.

The goal is to mimic what cmake does, without hardcoding anything. So if a user wants to do:

```
mkdir build 
premake5 --file=../premake5.lua
```

It should generate all workspace/projects inside the build folder, and not at the root.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

See [location](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/location), [_WORKING_DIR](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/_WORKING_DIR), and maybe [path.join](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/path.join).

```lua
project 'MyProject'
   location(path.join(_WORKING_DIR, 'MyProject'))
```